# Can't seem to get reverse relational field working from within a Neo field

Tags: matrix, relations, relatedto, plugin-neo

Has anyone managed to get reverse relations from a Neo field working? I have a Neo field containing an Entries field which works fine on the page/section entry where I have the Neo field, but I’m trying to get data out on that related entry page. Might just be bad coding on my part!

I've tried a simple test using a standard Matrix field and the reverse relation works fine, here's that working code:

```
{% set matrixRelatedEvents = craft.entries.section('events').relatedTo({
    targetElement: entry,
    field: 'matrixField'
}) %}
```

This is my Neo reverse relation code which is currently not working:

```
{% set neoRelatedEvents = craft.entries.section('events').relatedTo({
    targetElement: entry,
    field: 'neoField'
}) %}
```

Any ideas or is it not possible?